# How do I set XP levels to a scoreboard objective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to set the XP levels to a scoreboard objective. I tried getting the two variables and then changing it based on their difference, but the result increases when it is supposed to decrease and vice-versa.
Edit: Commands come from

Comment: You should provide the commands you're using that aren't working. That way we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an easy way to do this (there may be a trick I'm missing), but it's somewhat possible with a number of command blocks and a binary-search-like method. I'll use a dummy objective called "ExpController" for this example.

After you've changed the scoreboard objective, to set your experience to the objective, run the following commands in this order:

```
/xp -1000000000l @a
/xp 512l @a[score_ExpController_min=512]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=512] ExpController 512
/xp 256l @a[score_ExpController_min=256]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=256] ExpController 256
/xp 128l @a[score_ExpController_min=128]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=128] ExpController 128
/xp 64l @a[score_ExpController_min=64]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=64] ExpController 64
/xp 32l @a[score_ExpController_min=32]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=32] ExpController 32
/xp 16l @a[score_ExpController_min=16]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=16] ExpController 16
/xp 8l @a[score_ExpController_min=8]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=8] ExpController 8
/xp 4l @a[score_ExpController_min=4]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=4] ExpController 4
/xp 2l @a[score_ExpController_min=2]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=2] ExpController 2
/xp 1l @a[score_ExpController_min=1]
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_ExpController_min=1] ExpController 1
```

If you want to use numbers higher than 1023, which is the maximum the commands above will go currently, continue on the pattern (e.g: 1024, 2048, doubling each time, placing the new commands just after the first command).

All players' ExpController scores will be 0 after this. If you want to keep your EXP score as it is, you should clone it to a temp objective right before you do this, and use the temp objective for the above commands:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] ExpTemp = @a[c=1] ExpMain
```

Comment: how would this follow a timer(if it decreases?)

Comment: @Baboom1 When the score changes, you need to run these commands, and the player's XP will be set to the objective.

Comment: but wouldnt it update kind of slowly?

Answer (score -2):

check this formula calculator out http://pernsteiner.org/minecraft/levelcalc.html copy down the formulas to command blocks.